# libGDX - set TiledMapTile textureregion

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a way to set to some tiles a texture region that I want?

I see that I can only get the TextureRegion

```
/** @return texture region used to render the tile */
public TextureRegion getTextureRegion ();
```

But if I render my tiles with the tiledmaprenderer class, I see some wierd lines over my tiles
[image]

I want to provide a texture region for every tile, from code.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you would be better of with extruded tiles in your atlas.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038033/why-do-textures-flicker-when-camera-moves/24039064#24039064

Comment: @DavidSaltaresMárquez i don't have any atlas.. i just have a texture that holds every tile. Is not made with texture atlas..