# Why do textures flicker when camera moves?

Tags: java, opengl, camera, libgdx

I implemented a top view camera which moves with the player, only a bit slower using `camera.position.lerp`. The problem is that the textures are flashing (flickering) a little because i have scaled my textures. If I use normal size of textures the flickering stops. Does anyone have any ideas on how to move the camera with zoom (or textures scaled - same thing) without getting the textures to flicker (or flash)? I use linear filtering and load every asset from an atlas. I saw this problem on multiple forums, but no answer. I wanted to load higher resolution textures and resize them in code, that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Your min filter for the texture should be MipmapLinearLinear or at least MipmapLinearNearest. That should help quite a bit. Is the flickering happening everywhere, or only on the edges of sprites?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. The filtering Linear was different from MipMapLinear. I switched it and now I have no flickering.

Comment: Also changing the filter to MipMapLinearLinear blurs the textures. Is this a side effect?

Comment: If your problem is what I am thinking, that flickering is actually high-frequency noise. This happens when the sampled image has ***too many*** possible texels to select from at a certain location. The slightest difference in camera angle will change the cluster of 4 texels that are averaged together for linear texture filtering. Mipmapping changes this by creating lower-resolution images for minification at greater distance. You might consider it blurring, but it is technically a form of anti-aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed 2 problems with the help I got from these 2 posts. But i have one more (I hope this is the last one). As you know I am using lerp to move the camera, but for the alpha value 0.5 or lower, which gives the slow effect to the camera, when the view gets very close to the target it trembles. I know this is from the alpha value being too small, but if i make it bigger the camera moves too fast. Is there any way to make a better interpolation to move the camera a little slower than the player?                                EDIT:The tremble is far more visible on Y axis.

Comment: MipMapLinearNearest can have the effect of making the texture look too blurry depending on scale, because it might pick the lower resolution mip of the two nearest sized mips. MipMapLinearLinear should give you a very clean blend of the two mips. I'd have to see a comparison screenshot of Linear vs MipMapLinearLinear to know what you mean by it being blurry.

Comment: As for your question about lerping the camera, you'll need to create a new question for that so you can provide code for how you're handling your camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extrude the borders of your sprites in the atlas. The *Extrude* option tends to be close to the *Padding* ones.

[image: Extrude in TexturePacker]

Most texture packers support that feature and Libgdx will pick that information up from the `atlas` file straight away.

This way you get to use the filter you want.

Comment: I can't find an extrude option on libGDX texture packer. It might not have such an option.

Comment: In libGDX TexturePacker it's just a checkbox that says "duplicate padding". But it looks like your flickering had more to do with not using mipmaps in the first place. You do also need to do this though.